# Nested Requests in a list, Angular 5

Tags: angular

i'm having a little bit trouble at work, i'm new using angular but i search a lot before i tried ask you guys.

Let's imagine the follow situation, i have an API with 2 endpoints:

The first one returns any people data: "api/v1/people/1"

```
{ id: 1, name: 'john', age: '55' }
```

And the second one is a list that returns every one related to a person: "api/v1/people/1/related"

```
{ 
   id: 1,
   father: {
     id: 33,    
   },
   childrens: [
     {id: 34, childrens: [
               { id: 76, childrens: []},
               { id: 532, childrens: []}
              ]
      },
    {id: 354, childrens: [
               { id: 7546, childrens: []},
               { id: 53122, childrens: []}
              ]
 }
```

I need to get this hierarchical object merging the return of the first service in each person in the second service.

The result may be something like this:

```
{ 
   id: 1, name: 'some name', age: 23  
   father: {
     id: 33, name: 'some name', age: 23  
   },
   childrens: [
     {id: 34, name: 'some name', age: 23   childrens: [
               { id: 76, name: 'some name', age: 23   childrens: []},
               { id: 532, name: 'some name', age: 23   childrens: []}
              ]
      },
     {id: 354, name: 'some name', age: 23   childrens: [
               { id: 7546, name: 'some name', age: 23   childrens: []},
               { id: 53122, name: 'some name', age: 23   childrens: []}
              ]
 }
```

I Know that is possible using HttpClient and RxJS, bit i tried so many options and get nothing.

Can you help me with that?

Ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Observable.combineLatest` from RxJS (`npm install rxjs`):

**Firstly**, call the `/api` individually and on success set the store values

`api.service.ts`

```
import HttpClient from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

export class ApiService {
   constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
   getPersonData(personId: string): Observable<any> {
      const headers: {.....}; // set headers as required for the api call
      return this.http.get(`api/v1/people/${personId}`, {headers});
   }

   getDependents(personId: string): Observable<any> {
      const headers: {.....}; // set headers as required for the api call
      return this.http.get(`api/v1/people/${personId}/related`, {headers}); 
   }
}
```

**next** you need to store these returned data in redux store variables (you can search on how to set this up in your js/ts code easliy)

`store.ts`
say these are the store variables set:

```
personData: any;
dependentData: any;
```

**finally** in you component class, use `Observable.combineLatest` to combine and map data when both the data is available:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {select} from '@angular-redux/store';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/combineLatest';

@Component({....})
export class DataComponent {

   @select() readonly personData: Observable<any>;
   @select() readonly dependentData: Observable<any>;

   getCombinedData() {
      Observable.combineLatest(personData, dependentData)
                .filter((personData, dependentData) => !!personData && !!dependentData) // filter to ensure subscribe does not trigger if any of the two params are undefined
                .subscribe([personData, dependentData]: [any, any]) {
                // now use lodash or javascript map to combine the two data sets returned
       };
   }
}
```

Hope this provides the required solution for you!

Comment: i will try it, ty